# Obsolete OxyPlot package in Nuget

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, oxyplot

Good Day everyone. I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable Application. I want to create Charts using **Oxyplot**. And I was able to install it in NuGet.

But i saw the description stating

> "Please use the platform specific packages, this package is obsolete."

[image]

What should I do with this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it means that you have to download Oxyplot.Wpf if you are going to work with wpf, or Oxyplot.xamarin.android if working with xamarin in android, and not the main one.

Comment: @Kierenenko I wasn't able to install Oxyplot.xamarin.android Sir. There's an error. http://prntscr.com/buai98

Comment: Looks like core version does not match. Try to clean everything and install Oxyplot.Xamarin.Android or just downgrade Oxyplot.Core to 1.0.0-unstable1983.

Comment: I downloaded Oxyplot from xamarin component store and it worked nice. It worse to try it, I think. https://components.xamarin.com/view/oxyplot 
You should import valid build targets for each platform.